# Clickable activities list Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, android-intent

I'm retrieving data to list and I need to make 2 different intents. "Activities" needs to start "e" intent and rest starts "i" intent.

```
class MyAdapter(private val context : Activity, private val arrayList : ArrayList<Person>) : ArrayAdapter<Person>(context,
    R.layout.list_item, arrayList)      {


    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

        val inflater : LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val view : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null)

        val imageView : ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic)
        val activities : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.activity_name)
        val person_name : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.name_list)
        val activity_time : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.time)
        val checkbox : ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)
        val person_icon : ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.person_icon)

        imageView.setImageResource(arrayList[position].imageID)
        activities.text = arrayList[position].activities
        person_name.text = arrayList[position].name
        activity_time.text = arrayList[position].activityTime
        checkbox.setImageResource(arrayList[position].checkbox)
        person_icon.setImageResource(arrayList[position].person_icon)



        return view
    }
}
```

```
binding.listview.adapter = MyAdapter(this, personArrayList)
        binding.listview.isClickable = true
        binding.listview.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val name = name[position]
            val activities = activities[position]
            val activityTime = activityTime[position]
            val description = description[position]
            val imageID = imageID[position]
            val i = Intent(this, DescriptionActivity::class.java)
            val e = Intent(this, ProfileScreen::class.java)
            i.putExtra("name", name)
            i.putExtra("activityTime", activityTime)
            e.putExtra("activities", activities)
            i.putExtra("imageID", imageID)`your text`
            i.putExtra("description", description)
            startActivity(i)
        }
```

startActivity (e) overrides startActivity(i)
and making activities OnClickListener crashes the app.

Comment: It's not really clear from your description what you're trying to do. You have some condition that determines whether you want to open DescriptionActivity or ProfileScreen? What is that condition?

Comment: Sorry, Im new to kotlin and its hard for me to explain. 
So bascially i have a list of persons, and I need to make 2 intents in this depending on what I click. I need to have Profile Screen intent for activities and DescriptionActivity for the rest. I want them to work like OnClickListener.

Comment: It would help to understand what you're trying to do if we knew what your class is that you have a list of that you're showing. But also it looks like you have six different lists, which is really weird. There is `personArrayList`, `name`, `activities`, `activityTime`, `description`, and `imageID`. Why is this not a single list of some class?

Comment: I am making list of persons, that are running some sort of activities on gym. I am fetching them from data. For example what i have in data: Kaya,boxing,11am. All i do is typing strings there and it automatically ads a new position on list. Its just an easier way for me to add new persons and their activities on gym. It is possible to do without making a list, and fetching data, but it would take much more time. I know its hard to understand me without seeing this whole project. Its all kinda complicated.

Comment: I think you just need an if/else in that click listener but your description is too vague to say what that would look like.